# Método da Bisecção com Python

Tags: python, métodos-estáticos

Estou desenvolvimento um programa para calcular métodos numéricos. Inicie pelos métodos de confinamento, neste caso um deles é o da Bisecção.

Não estou conseguindo printar as iterações que o método realiza...Criei um função genérica para o método, porém quando chamo ela dentro do meu `if` responsável pelo método escolhido pelo usuário, a mesma não retorna nenhum valor...

```
def bisection(f, a, b, valor_tolerancia, numero_iteracoes):

    i = 1
    fa = f(a)

    while i <= numero_iteracoes:
        x = a+(a-b)/2.0
        fx = f(x)

        if ((f(x) == 0) or ((b-a)/2.0 < valor_tolerancia):
            return x
        else:
            i = i + 1
            if (f(a)*f(x) > 0):
                a = x
                fa = fx
            else:
                b = x
    raise NameError("Você excedeu o Numéro de Iterações!");


if metodo_escolhido == 1:
    print("# Método da Bisecção #")
    print("\n")

    valor_a = float(input("Valor de a: "))
    valor_b = float(input("Valor de b: "))
    valor_tolerancia = float(input("Tolerancia: "))
    numero_iteracoes = float(input("Digite o numero de iterações: "))

calculo_bissec = bisection(f,a,b,valor_tolerancia,num)
print(calculo_bissec)
```

Comment: Aqui: calculo_bissec = bisection(f,a,b,valor_tolerancia,num) não deveria ser: calculo_bissec = bisection(f, valor_a, valor_b, valor_tolerancia, numero_iteracoes)? Também não vi a definição de f.

Comment: f seria a equação em que o usuário iria digitar, porém não sei como realizar tal operação...pois a maioria do conteúdo relacionado, o programador já coloca a função e não usuário.

Comment: Talvez o uso de eval possa ajuda-lo.